# Change theme for a specific item in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-theme

I have a program which uses the "android:Theme.Holo" for the fragment. Is there a way to lower the theme for an editText to android:Theme ? I tried to do this

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            style="@android:style/android:Theme"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_text_d"
            >
        </EditText>
```

in the hopes that the edit text would look like the old background of white. I don't want to use a custom background but is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this in your Theme:

```
<style name="myTheme"  parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    <item name="editTextStyle">@style/MyWidget.EditText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyWidget.EditText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: I believe adding `style="@android:style/Widget.EditText"` directly to the EditText in the layout xml will also work, without the need for custom themes.

Comment: I get error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'editTextStyle' and addind the style="@android:style/Widget.EditText" directly doesn't do anything

Comment: Try this : <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/MyWidget.EditText</item>